# Any downside/danger to changing an EBS volume type for a live database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

Starting to need to scale a relatively random-access workflow on MongoDB, and iotop indicates we're fully utilizing our IO. Looks like AWS allows you to switch volume types to provisionable IOPS without downtime (and to add more IOPS), but is there any downside or danger to doing this on a master database node? When something sounds too good to be true...

Comment: Try it out in your test system. Run a load test and watch the behaviour. It could vary between nothing or degraded performance while the database storage is migrated to a different device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be seamless.

Of course, you want to be prepared for the possibility of problems, so it makes sense to snapshots your volume and ensure that you have a backup plan, but...

> While the volume is in the `optimizing` state, your volume performance will be in between the source and target configuration specifications. Transitional volume performance will be no less than the source volume performance. If you are downgrading IOPS, transitional volume performance will be no less than the target volume performance.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html

The process is smooth, and the probable reason is that EBS *already* has internal replication.

You may not know that your volume always exists in two places, with the replica being on different hardware in the same availability zone.  If the volume fails, the replica takes over, and becomes the master, and seeks out a new storage node within the cluster to replicate itself onto, to continue to preserve the refundancy.

In fact, in normal operation, if the master volume loses its replica, it searches for a new replication target and I/O freezes until a target is acquired -- normally, within milliseconds.  EBS volumes never operate without a replica, even though this is hidden from the user.

So, reading between the lines -- and not to diminish the genuine magic involved here -- it seems sensible to come to this conclusion: relative to the complexity and sophistication in EBS's transparent replication in normal, everyday operation... what the engineers have likely done is not significanly different: they've harnessed parts of this same mechanism, but the volume replicates itself to devices capable of offering the new volume attributes.  When the replication is complete, the replica takes over... or maybe it's in stages: given that your EBS volume was never on one single disk, anyway (even forgetting about replication, EBS provisions a single "volume" across multiple storage devices to begin with) the documented behavior starts to make sense.

So real "too good to be true part" is actually a natural extension of something EBS has been quietly doing all along.

Of course, this is largely speculation on my part, but it seems plausible in light of what is publicly known about EBS.

*Aside: a significant [EBS outage](https://aws.amazon.com/message/65648/) occurred in one one availability zone in one region, a few years back, and one of the key factors was a storm of "re-mirroring" attempts as volumes thought they had lost their replicas and began frantically searching for a new nodes with sufficient capacity to agree to become their new replica.*